# How to set static variable and instantiate only one prefab for the AR Core demo

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to modify the demo scene in the Unity AR Core SDK and 
I've created a static bool variable `isCreated` to check if the Andy prefab is created.

In the following check

```
if (Session.Raycast(m_firstPersonCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position), raycastFilter, outHit))
```

I've set the variable to be true and then put another check here

```
if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch (0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began || isCreated) {
    return;
}
```

But for some reason, the variable is **never gets set to true**.
I've also noticed [this error](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/3) in the logs, and can't help but wonder if it somehow prevents it from getting set.

> 08-29 14:11:40.564 13392-13407/? E/Unity: OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_ENUM: enum argument out of range
>   (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GfxDeviceGLES.cpp Line: 368)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how badly you want your boolean to static, but I achieved the same result by doing something similar:

```
bool m_placed = false; // under the color array
```

Then just like you, I check for it here:

```
if (Session.Raycast(m_firstPersonCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position), raycastFilter, out hit) && !m_placed) {
    ...
    m_placed = true; // At the very end of this block
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I **did not** have add anything to

```
if (Session.Raycast(m_firstPersonCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position), raycastFilter, outHit))
```

The OpenGL error is a common issue that has already been raised. It should not affect this.

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/3